# Robot Framework: no logs generated when running as part of a web app

Tags: python, django, robotframework

I'm building a Django web app that runs robot test cases.  I execute the test cases using a simple call to `robot.run`, but I am not getting `report.html` or `log.html` files.  I do get an `output.xml` file, and it contains an error:

```
Unexpected error: ValueError: signal only works in main thread
```

and `robot.run` returns the result code 255, regardless of whether the test cases pass.

This only happens when I attempt to execute the robot tests within the web app.  When I run `pybot` or open a python shell and execute `robot.run` within the python shell, everything works file.

I did find [this bug report](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/1848) which talks about robot not running properly in a non-main thread.  But the test cases do run and produce console output as well as `output.xml`.  It is only the report and log files that do not get created.

Is there any way to resolve this issue, or am I at the mercy of that bug getting fixed?